# asp.net,c#.net repeated fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net webpage `abc.aspx`
it contains

```
        <td class="style1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="chqdt1" runat="server" Width="71px"></asp:TextBox>
            <a href="javascript:OpenCalFuture('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chqdt1');">
            <img border="0" height="16" src="cal.gif" width="16" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="add" style="margin-left: 0px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
```

I want on each button click event create new row with new textbok with calender field created

Comment: i am using add row javascript..so after button click new row with textbox is created.but problem is that..selecting calender in last textbox...its focus on the first text box...plz give m a solution

Answer (score 1):

handle button's OnClick event and put in handler code like that:

```
TextBox2 = New TextBox()
TextBox2.ID = "TextBox2"
TextBox2.Style("Width") = "71px"
Form1.Controls.Add(TextBox2)
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515

Comment: i am using add row javascript..so after button click new row with textbox is created.but problem is that..selecting calender in last textbox...its focus on the first text box...plz give m a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick answer:

1. First create a PlaceHolder for your textboxes.
2. Handle buttons OnClick event
3. Generate TextBox and Literal controls for your textbox and calendar field.
4. Add the generated controls to PlaceHolder.

Code sample:

```
<td class="style1">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder1" runat="server" />    
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Button OnClick="Button1_Click" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="add" style="margin-left: 0px" />
</td>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.ID = "myTextBoxID";

    Literal literalCal = new LiteralCalendar();
    literalCal.Text = 
        "<a href=\"javascript:OpenCalFuture('" + textbox.ClientID + "');\"><img border=\"0\" height=\"16\" src=\"cal.gif\" width=\"16\" /></a>";

    placeholder1.Controls.Add(textbox);
    placeholder1.Controls.Add(literalCal);
}
```

The sample above might not be a complete (or valid) code because I didn't test it, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: i am using add row javascript..so after button click new row with textbox is created.but problem is that..selecting calender in last textbox...its focus on the first text box...plz give m a solution

Comment: i am using add row javascript..so after button click new row with textbox is created.but problem is that..selecting calender in last textbox...its focus on the first text box...plz give m a solution

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do what @Dima says but instead of the Forms1.Controls you should use a Placeholder control and write:

```
placeholder.Controls.Add(TextBox2)
```

Then you'd also do:

```
TextBox2.Focus();
```

to have the focus on that textbox.